# how to resize columns with mouse inside ng-grid control

Tags: ng-grid

Hello a have a simple question I have defined columns with property resizable: true.
How do I manage to let user re-size column with their mouse, like they will do in most grid control?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Columns are resizable by default, but you have to activate resizing on the whole grid by setting enableColumnResize to true in the grid options. See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9EkdMgn6kXryHs7nxak8?p=preview).

```
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    enableColumnResize: true
};
```

Comment: also add , 'ui.grid.resizeColumns' module and in div tag ui-grid-resize-columns <div ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" ui-grid-exporter ui-grid-selection ui-grid-pinning ui-grid-resize-columns class="grid">
                            </div>